How to add childcomponent to mudstack in my code
 private RenderFragment RenderSimpleElement() => builder =>
    {
        int seq = 0;
      
        builder.OpenComponent<MudStack>(seq++);
        
        builder.AddAttribute(seq++,"Child","");
      
        builder.OpenComponent<StoragePlace>(seq++);
        builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "Name", "kukuku");
        builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "Width", "180px");
        builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "Height", "260px");
        builder.CloseComponent();

        
        builder.OpenComponent<StoragePlace>(seq++);
        builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "Name", "hahaha");
        builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "Width", "180px");
        builder.AddAttribute(seq++, "Height", "260px");
        builder.CloseComponent();

        builder.CloseComponent();
    };

this cant work!
I can compile it, but when rendering this interface, the following error occurs. I think it might not be possible to add child components to the mud stack like this：
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error: No element is currently associated with component 78)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error: No element is currently associated with component 78

so what is the correct method?
i need to add childcomponent to mudstack this way.
